# How to send data between two Android-devices without server through the Internet?

Tags: android, networking, p2p

Is there any way to communicate between Android devices directly?  How to implement Server-type node on clients side?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about p2p connections using wifi and/or hotspot of the phone, the link below may help:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html